# How to compile sveltekit library to plain javascript and resources?

Tags: sveltekit

I've created my library with `npm init svelte` and selected *Library skeleton project*. After writing my component and doing the production build I see in `package` directory that it is not plain JS because it also contains `MyComponent.svelte`. I would like my component library to be used by plain JS (or TS) projects. How can I compile it to be pure JS with css and image resources (and `*.d.ts`)?

Comment: How is SvelteKit related to creating a component library? It's an application framework.

Comment: @H.B. run `npm init svelte my-project` and the 1st question will be what type of project you would like to create. Third option is _Library skeleton project_. See also for example https://medium.com/mkdir-awesome/how-to-create-svelte-component-libraries-with-sveltekit-98fd2ff12f0f

Comment: I switched from sveltekit to Svelte project created with Vite `npm create vite` and there it works as I need. Note that I am very new to Svelte (it is my 1st Svelte project).

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly this allows the Svelte compiler to better optimize builds if these files can be used directly. (The `package.json` has a `"svelte"` property to identify the entry point for Svelte.)

You probably have to run a separate build process on the resulting package to fully compile everything ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75895650/546730)). The current packaging mechanism (`svelte-package`) has no options regarding this.