# How to compile Svelte 3 components into IIFE's that can be used in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, svelte, web-component, svelte-3, iife

I am making a web component in Vanilla JS that use a hidden `select` in the background and a `div` and `ul>li` in front. It became a bit complex with fetching data from an api, ect, so I transitioned to Svelte to simplify it and make it more readable.

Now I've tried for 2 days to export the component as an IIFE. I just can't seem to figure out how. I might be mistaken, but I thought that was one of the main features of Svelte - to make reusable components that can be used anywhere. Making it was the easy part, but now I want to load it and use it directly in the browser (with `<script src=""></script>`). I thought that should be easy?

I use Svelte 3 (3.57.0) with Vite 4 (4.2.1), and I have tried both `npm create svelte` to create a library project with SvelteKit and `npm init vite` with `svelte` as framework.

I've read quite a lot of the documentation for Vite and Svelte, but it feels overwhelming and I can't seem to find a configuration that works.

*Does anyone know how to compile components to IIFEs in Svelte?*

Comment: Why would you try to do that? Why not compile it as a regular module instead of polluting global scope?

Comment: I'm not super up to date on 'regular modules'. I'm primarily looking for a way to drop in / use a svelte component in a regular HTML document. To make the question more specific I went with IIFE's as that is what I know. Do you know about any resources for compiling them into such a module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, SvelteKit only pre-processes components so they can be used by any Svelte project. The Svelte files are then only compiled to plain JS in the projects that use the component library.

You could add a separate Vite config to fully compile the components to JS files, e.g.

```js
// vite.js.config.js
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.js'),
            name: 'Components',
            fileName: 'components',
        },
        outDir: 'dist-js',
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte(),
    ],
});
```

This build operates on the output of SvelteKit which is written to `dist` and creates a separate JS output in `dist-js`.

To run Vite with a specific config you can use the `-c` argument:

```bash
vite -c vite.js.config.js build
```

This could e.g. be added as a script in `package.json`.

Vite in [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) automatically outputs an [ES module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) file that requires an `import` and a UMD file which, when no other loaders are in scope, will define the components globally on an object with the name given in `build.lib.name`.

So in the above example, if you export `Component` from the `index.js` file, you could construct it via `new Components.Component({ ... })` with the [client-side API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! That was very enlightening and helpful - works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for this — I just went through the proces with my own project in Svelte 4, here's the repo in case anyone wants another example to reference: https://github.com/kitschpatrol/tweakpane-css