# Why does Vite 5 crash in library mode when building a Svelte-component as an ES module?

Tags: svelte, vite

### The Problem

I want to compile a svelte component (using svelte 4.2.7) to an es module using vite (version 5.0.3) but I can't seem to make it build. I have read the documentations on using [vite library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) and searched around stackoverflow for [similair questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832641/how-to-compile-svelte-3-components-into-iifes-that-can-be-used-in-vanilla-js).

I have nailed it down the issue to something to do with the library build step. Commenting the lib section in the vite config makes the build succeed (but obviously it doesn't compile it to an es module) and running it in dev mode seems to work.

The error I get is this:

```
✓ built in 209ms
[vite-plugin-sveltekit-compile] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')
✓ built in 569ms
error during build:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')
    at Object.handler (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/vite-bug/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@2.0.4_@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.1_svelte@4.2.8_vite@5.0.10/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/index.js:749:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PluginDriver.hookParallel (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/vite-bug/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18561:17)
    at async file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/vite-bug/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19559:13
    at async catchUnfinishedHookActions (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/vite-bug/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.9.1/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18983:16)
    at async build (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/vite-bug/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.0.10/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-R0I0XnyH.js:66815:22)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/vite-bug/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.0.10/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:845:9)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried using svelte 3.54.0 as well but the error I get then seems to be of a similar nature:

```
✓ built in 395ms
[vite-plugin-sveltekit-compile] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
✓ built in 1.49s
error during build:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
    at Object.handler (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/test2/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/index.js:744:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PluginDriver.hookParallel (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/test2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25466:17)
    at async file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/test2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:26792:13
    at async catchUnfinishedHookActions (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/test2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25910:16)
    at async build (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/test2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-68d1a114.js:48085:22)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///Users/cascading-jox/Coding/test2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:842:9)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

### The Code

This is my vite.config.js:

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'lib/index.js'),
            name: 'Test',
            // the proper extensions will be added
            fileName: 'test',
            formats: ['es']
        }
    },
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
});
```

This is my index.js file:

```js
// Reexport your entry components here
import Test from './Test.svelte';
export { Test };
```

I uploaded my test project to github [here](https://github.com/cascading-jox/svelte-vite-lib-mode-issue).